# laravel , how to crop and pass the image using Ajax , i know that , but the data is serialized , i can't read my cropped image

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a form with a lot of inputs.
Its a `multipart/form`. I'm using laravel.

Anyway, I have a list that shows all users, it uses Ajax, but when I try to save the croped image as well, i just can't read it.

Here is my code in blade :

```
<form id="frm-insert" role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ URL::to('student/store') }}">

               <div class="image-editor" style="float: right">
                    <input type="file" id="userimage" name="userimage" class="cropit-image-input">
                    <div class="cropit-preview"><img src="{{asset('images/default1.jpg')}}" id="defaultimage" style="cursor:pointer;width:248px;height: 248px;" /></div>
                    <small style="color: red;">@foreach($errors->get('userimage') as $message ) {{$message}}   @endforeach</small>
                    <div class="image-size-label">

                        برش تصویر
                    </div>
                    <input type="range" class="cropit-image-zoom-input">
                    <input name="image-data" class="hidden-image-data" />
                </div>
                <div id="result" style="display: none">
                    <code>$form.serialize() =</code>
                    <code id="result-data"></code>
                </div>
```

And here is the ajax part:

```
    $('#frm-insert').on('submit',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    var url = $(this).attr('action');
    var post = $(this).attr('method');
    $.ajax({
        type:post,
        url:url,
        data:data,
        dataty:'json',
        success:function (data) {
            var tr = $('<tr/>',{
                id : data.id
            });
            tr.append($('<td/>',{
                text:data.id
            })).append($('<td/>',{
                text:data.cell_phone
            })).append($('<td/>',{
                text:data.email
            })).append($('<td/>',{
                text:data.created_at_shamsi
            })).append($('<td/>',{
                text:data.gender
            })).append($('<td/>',{
                text:data.username
            })).append($('<td/>',{
                text:data.family
            })).append($('<td/>',{
                text:data.name
            })).append($('<td/>',{


                html : '<a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" id="view" data-id="' + data.id + '">تغییر رمز</a> '
                + '<a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="edit" data-id="' + data.id + '">ویرایش</a> ' +
                '<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="del" data-id="' + data.id + '">حذف</a>'
            }));
```

And in controller I just can't get `$request->get('image-data')`, I have already tried `var data = new Form()` and so on ... but it dos not work for me.

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: You should ask for a specific issue you might have, asking "why is this code not working" is not valid.
Can you provide more context or some error logs?

Comment: the issue is i use something called cropit.js , i use it to crop the image , but that is not the problem . the first code i posted . thats the problem . i don't know why i can not read image-data ( that is the cropped version of image ) . it is really simple , i just don't know why it returns null

Comment: @JoaquimLey you are the only one that answered , pleassse help me :(

Comment: @JoaquimLey : do you want me to update the code ? so it is more clear ?

Comment: @JoaquimLey I fount the problem , it is croped after the post , how do i stop it ?

Comment: @JoaquimLey thats why it is null , because it is filled after the post .

Comment: before submitting the form you should console log your data .so that you will come to know that what actual data you getting at form submit.